Function Checks two Cells and Return a Text in Google Sheets
I have the following formula in column F
=IF(ISBLANK($D15); ""; "text?")

I want the same formula to check column B that has a checkbox if it's checked to return also “text”.
I have tried the:
=IF(ISBLANK($C15:$D15); ""; "text?")

But it didn't work.
How should I write the formula?


You may try:
=IF(or(B15;D15<>"");"text?";)


No it didn't work

Change C15 to B15 if checkbox is in Column_B. if it still doesnt work, consider sharing a test sheet showcasing your input & expected output

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IolfFU06c8AGb-bDstZkqA-ruWv3eqUzuA6RAxUqA8Y/edit?usp=sharing

Showcase in your sheet clearly what are the inputs, Where you've tried the formula & ideally what should've been the output if the formula one is going wrong

F15 & F16
I changed the access to editing

F15 & F16
I changed the access to editing
Your formula works when both are checked. I am trying to make it work for either B or D like cases B14 and D14 and if both B15 & D15 are selected.

**Formula Updated
